# how to simulate input event on input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    console.log('323');
});

$('#btn').click();
console is written `323`
```

I want the same with `input` event, like this:

```
$('#inp').on('input', function(){
    console.log('323');
});

$('#inp').input();
```

error - `input is not a function`

So how to simulate `input` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `trigger` on the element, passing the name of the event whose jQuery handler you want to invoke:

```js
$('#inp').on('input', function(){
    console.log('323');
});

$('#inp').trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp">
```